# Running scripts with checkboxes on SSIS with visual basic

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have some scripts that I need to run but they vary depending on the package Im using.
I need a script task to show me the checkboxes with the script names and run each one I mark.

for example:

I have number1.sql, number2.sql, number3.sql, number4.sql and number5.sql.
I want to run only number1 and number3. I need a checkbox window so I can mark the ones I want to run.
I just need a script to make them run if checked.

Comment: That seems an odd requirement since most SSIS packages run in an automated fashion from a SQL Server job and thus would not want to have user interaction.

Comment: Saying what you need isn't a question.  Are you hoping somebody will write it for you for free?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the state of the checkbox, write your code to say if checkbox is ticked or true, run the code you want.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx